# Get all non-revoked publishers for an Event Hub

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

If I wish to retrieve all revoked publishers of an Event Hub, I can invoke:

`NamespaceManager.GetRevokedPublishers()`

How do I get a list of the non-revoked publishers of an Event Hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built-in way to do that.

[Authentication and Security in Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview) is best handled by [SAS tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#sas-tokens) generated using the `RootManageSharedAccessKey` usually generated by a service secured and owned by you.

Since your service generates these tokens, you should be able to maintain a list of publishers that you've provisioned tokens for.

Event Hub can directly validate whether a SAS token is valid and uses the revoke list to block access for clients using a token from that list.

Another way (although not recommended) is to directly provide access to the Event Hub by [Creating Authorization Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/createorupdateauthorizationrule) on the resource itself and using its [keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/listkeys).
Note that there is a [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas) of 12 for these rules.